# string char rotation

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge :

Given a string rotate every char by its index. `e.g --> 'Hello' should be 'Hfnos'`.

---

## Input :

Input is given as string `s` length of string is  `2 < s ≤ 100`. Input will either be alphabet , number or one of the following whitespace , ! , @ , # , $ , % , ^ , & , * , ( , )

---

## Output :

Output will be a string with all characters rotated by their index. Example given above.

---

## Examples :

```
Input                     Output

Hello World!              Hfnos%]vzun,
Who                       Wiq
PPCG                      PQEJ
```

---

## Note :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes in each language wins.

Comment: what happens when a character goes over `~`? e.g. what's the output for `~~` (or is that not a valid input?)

Comment: @dzaima : That is not a valid input.

Comment: How about `{|}`? Is it invalid too? Please be more specific. Also, if the resulting code poing cannot go beyond 126, it's a _shift_ rather than _rotation_, isn't it?

Comment: But if the length of `s` can be 3000 ...

Comment: @Shaggy Good point. The challenge it not only unclear but apparently contradictory

Comment: _No need to check for edge cases_ What does that mean exactly?

Comment: @LuisMendo : Updated , thanks

Comment: @Shaggy : updated

Comment: Do we rotate over ASCII values **32-126**, or between the allowed input characters?

Comment: Perhaps consider taking some more time to refine your answers and avoid confusion. [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) can help you with that.

Comment: By the way, when you say 'alphabet' I think you mean 'letter'

Comment: @AsoneTuhid : thanks. this is one of many things i need to fix

Comment: @AsoneTuhid Stating to use the Sandbox is useless against him.. I think he's allergic to it or something.. In every single one of his challenges (except his Diamond challenge) it was suggested to use the Sandbox ([see these screenshots as prove of those comments](https://i.imgur.com/Os9JO3d.png)). And he only used it once thus far for about 5 hours (the yellow circled one). _Muhammad_, I know it can be annoying to wait 72+ hours when you have a good idea for a challenge, but you're kinda starting to piss me (and others) off by not using the Sandbox when everyone suggests it every time again..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen : I apologize I will use the sand box next time.

Comment: Hmm, my comment sounds more hostile than I meant it to be now that I read it back again.. Sorry about that. Just wanted to let you understand the Sandbox is there for a reason, and actually helps a lot to have questions answered there instead of here. I actually liked some of the challenges you've posted thus far, but when you posted them it was initially lacking some key parts that caused confusion. In the Sandbox those lacking parts can be fixed, and then here it will get more upvotes. You'll probably still get questions, but a lot less when most is already covered after the Sandbox. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen : I will remember to post in the sand box.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>37</s> <s>36</s> 28 bytes

```
zipWith($)(iterate(succ.)id)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzvyqzIDyzJENDRVMjsyS1KLEkVaO4NDlZTzMzRfN/bmJmnoKtQkFpSXBJkU@egopCmoKSB1BrvtL/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

How it works

```
iterate(succ.)id     -- starting with the identity function 'id' this
                     -- creates an infinite list of function where the next
                     -- element has one more 'succ' (the successor function)
                     -- composed to it than the current element:
                     -- -> [id, succ.id, succ.succ.id, succ.succ.succ.id, ...]
zipWith ($) (   )    -- combine the above list and the input string
                     -- elementwise with the function application operator '$'.
                     -- 1st char c0:            id $ c0 =            c0
                     -- 2nd char c1:       succ.id $ c1 =       succ c1
                     -- 3rd char c2:  succ.succ.id $ c2 = succ (succ c2)
                     -- etc.
```

Edit: -8 bytes thanks to @Angs

Comment: `zipWith($)(iterate(succ.)id)` saves some bytes

Comment: Also 28 bytes: `zipWith(\n c->[c..]!!n)[0..]`

Answer (score -1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda I:[chr(ord(c)+i)for i,c in enumerate(I)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDsIgFEV3vuJtQKwOjk3q4qDdujnUDggYnqE8QmiMX4@C27035574yY7CsfjhXrxaH0bB2M/aJUHJCC13KJ@UADsNGMCGbbVJZStGuRQMccswwMyv1nviHfwDvCl5U@vNtXWazhe@MNZM1dOePQOICUP@2YHvT5XkhxdhEF6glKx8AQ)

Answer (score -2):

## Japt, 2 bytes

```
c+
```

[Try it out here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Yys=&input=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISI=)

Comment: [JS, 31 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBEkAwDADAr@CUTPGDOjj5gasOiWFCTIvR18fuHt6Q5rhdd3PqQsbeku/6h5kiJGyPcAF8dUbffS6jmyab9Uwq1IquwFANJKLFqFGWskK0Hw) - will post when/if challenge is reopened.

Comment: This isn't rotation.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, what do you mean? It does exactly what the challenge asks.

Comment: The challenge says "*rotate every char by its index*". Rotation implies wrapping around. It's not clear exactly what permutation should be applied, so the question isn't really answerable at all at the moment, but this definitely isn't it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, nowhere in the spec does it mention wrapping around, nor is it covered in the test cases.